# How to restore Room database that i have exported?

Tags: android, android-room, database-backups

In my App i need to implement restoring room database that i have exported to local storage. i have managed to copy all 03 database files (.db -shm and wal) using get getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getAbsolutePath(). For replacing it back, i am copying these exported files back to original database path, which works fine, but no data is showing when i access it from inside the app. The exported database is clearly showing all the table with DB Browser tool. I am not sure why its not working.This is a backup button, which generates backup files. I am not sure if i am approaching it wrong or there is something wrong in my code.

```
backpathbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          String currentDBPath =
            getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getAbsolutePath();
    String backupDBPath = "my_db";
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    String rot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File currentDB = new File(currentDBPath);
    File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

    if (currentDB.exists()) {
        try {
            db.close();
            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();
            backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath+"-shm");
            src = new FileInputStream(currentDB+"-shm").getChannel();
            dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();
            backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath+"-wal");
            src = new FileInputStream(currentDB+"-wal").getChannel();
            dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();}

            catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }}} });
```

Here is the restore button

```
restorebutton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            db.close();
            String back=
                    getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getAbsolutePath();
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
            String current = "my_db";
            String currentsh = "my_db-shm";
            String currentwl = "my_db-wal";      
            String filepath= sd+"/"+current;
            String shmfile= sd+"/"+currentsh;
            String currenwl= sd+"/"+currentwl;
            File dest=new File(back);
            Log.d(TAG, "Following files are in absolute path " + dest.list()); // returning null

            try {
                copyFile(filepath,dest);
                copyFile(shmfile,dest);
                copyFile(currenwl,dest);
                Log.d(TAG, "Copied Sucessfully "); // it Copies without error
               } 
                catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
}
```

Here is my copy file function

```
  public  void copyFile(String src, File dst) throws IOException
{

    FileChannel inChannel = new FileInputStream(String.valueOf(src)).getChannel();
    FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(dst).getChannel();
    try
    {
        inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (inChannel != null)
            inChannel.close();
        if (outChannel != null)
            outChannel.close();
    }
}
```

After returning back to my MainActivity, restored data is not showing, even after closing and reopening the app again.

Comment: "but no data is showing when i access it from inside the app" -- make sure that your `RoomDatabase` is closed before restoring from the backup. Open the database again after the restore operation is completed. Also, we do not have your `copyFile()` function, but I recommend that you use a `FileOutputStream` for writing, and that you call `flush()` and `getFD().sync()` on that `FileOutputStream` before you `close()` it, to ensure all bytes get written to disk before proceeding. Also, eventually, please move this disk I/O to a background thread.

Comment: As you can see i am calling db.close(), in my restore button click. I have also posted copy file function. It is still not working. Can you replace database files at internal storage? Under data/appdirectory/databases/ ? Could it be the cause ?

Comment: "As you can see i am calling db.close(), in my restore button click" -- we do not know what `db` is. "I have also posted copy file function" -- I stand by my recommendation from my previous comment. "Can you replace database files at internal storage?" -- yes.

Comment: Also note that you appear to be copying all three files to the same `dest` value, which does not seem to be correct.

Comment: dest is an absolute path, where original database resides. I am trying to replace it using copyFile.

Comment: But you have `copyFile(filepath,dest);` followed by `copyFile(shmfile,dest);` followed by `copyFile(currenwl,dest);`. You are using `dest` in all three cases, and you are not changing the value of `dest` between those calls. The second `copyFile()` will overwrite the results of the first `copyFile()`. The third `copyFile()` will overwrite the results of the second `copyFile()`. In your backup code, you are changing the value of `backupDB` before each copy operation.

Comment: Thank you for helping out. I have just create three new destination files and then called Copy files separately on each one. It didn't work. `File dbdes=new File(back);  File shmdes=new File(back),  File wldes=new File(back);  ` and called `copyFile(filepath,dbdes);` on each individually.

Comment: Creating new `File` objects for the same path does not help. You need to change the path to point to the correct destination file, with the correct filename. You are changing the path correctly in your backup code. You need to do the same sort of thing in your restore code.